# Padding in SQL query for fixed length output

Tags: sql

How can I use padding in  SQL

Example:

```
Select id from table;
```

Output:

```
123
```

I want the output should always be of 10 length with spaces padded at right side.

Comment: What database you are using? Syntax might be little different for each database

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server** you can use [`left()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`replicate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select left('123' + replicate(' ',10), 10)
```

For **MySql**, **Oracle** and **Postgresql** there is [`rpad()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad):

```
select rpad('123', 10, ' ')
```

Comment: How can i use it in a situation like:  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT id) as "id" from table

Comment: If id is the column you want to pad with spaces: `COUNT(DISTINCT rpad(id, 10, ' '))`