# Padding spaces in SQL

Tags: sql

How to add spaces in data when length of data is unknown?

When selecting character data, I'm trying to pad the data with spaces so that the length of what I'm returning is the same for all rows. For Instance Length should remain 15 always.

This will ultimately go into a report that has all fixed length columns so the size of the data returned for each field has to be consistent.

There needs to be padding done with spaces.

Comment: What does the manual suggest

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501717/padding-in-sql-query-for-fixed-length-output from earlier today.

Comment: [field]+SPACE(15-LEN([field]))

Comment: Roger Clerkwell : It is giving Null Pointer Exception for blank Values

Answer (score 3):

In any database, converting to a `char()` should work:

```
select cast(col as char(15))
```

The `char()` type is fixed length, padded with spaces.

The more typical method would be to pad the values with spaces.  The exact method for that varies by database.

Comment: very neat and simple :-)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can do as the follows:

```
-- Create a sample table
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Str VARCHAR(15)
);
--Insert some data
INSERT INTO T (Str) VALUES
('abc'), --3 chars
('abcdefg'), --7 chars
('abcrfhtkidleoky'); -- 15 chars

--See the data
SELECT *, LEN(Str) LN
FROM T;

--Update the table to add spaces
UPDATE T
SET Str = CONCAT(REPLICATE(' ', 15 - LEN(Str)), Str) --Add spaces
WHERE LEN(Str) < 15;

--See the updates
SELECT *, LEN(Str) LN
FROM T;
```

The first `SELECT` will return:

```
+----+-----------------+----+
| ID |       Str       | LN |
+----+-----------------+----+
|  1 | abc             |  3 |
|  2 | abcdefg         |  7 |
|  3 | abcrfhtkidleoky | 15 |
+----+-----------------+----+
```

The second `SELECT` (after updating the data) will return:

```
+----+-----------------+----+
| ID |       Str       | LN |
+----+-----------------+----+
|  1 |    abc          | 15 |
|  2 |    abcdefg      | 15 |
|  3 | abcrfhtkidleoky | 15 |
+----+-----------------+----+
```

See how it's working on a **[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8fb7819b6a84e53272abe7d92aee5409)**.

---

For SQLite you can do as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Str VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('abc'), --3 chars
('abcdefg'), --7 chars
('abcrfhtkidleoky'); -- 15 chars

SELECT *, LENGTH(Str) LN
FROM T;

UPDATE T
SET Str = Str || REPLACE(HEX(ZEROBLOB(15-LENGTH(Str))), '00', ' ')
WHERE LENGTH(Str) < 15;

SELECT *, LENGTH(Str) LN
FROM T;
```

Comment: Hi Sami, curious why you would ever update a table with blank spaces when you can add the spacing when you select?

Comment: It's the OP who want to do so not me, I just do what he ask for. Agree it's a horrible idea and makes no sense but ... it's his choice.

Comment: OK I thought he just needed on select not also update, yeah agree with you makes no sense on an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
isnull([field],'')+SPACE(15-LEN(isnull([field],'')))
```

Comment: Only do this for Select output though, don't up updating a table column with spaces.

Comment: Please also check out Shawn link above which uses: left(isnull([field],'') + replicate(' ',15), 15)